# What diagram is this?

Tags: diagram

I've been reading some -really- old slides about mozilla, and came across this diagram:

http://www.mozilla.org/newlayout/doc/gecko-overview_files/Slide0023.gif

but I never seen this sort of diagram before, it does not seem like a UML 2 diagram. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very old fashioned class diagram.  The little dots represent an interface.